# $_SERVER['argv'][0]; stopped working after php 4 to 5 update

Tags: php

Im fairly new to working with the $_SERVER var

Now Im trying to solve a problem with a website.

I got this line of code

```
initWithUrl("resources/includes/mrvr-members.table.inc.php", "<?PHP echo $_SERVER['argv'][0]; ?>");
```

This used to work all good.

```
<?PHP echo $_SERVER['argv'][0]; ?>");
```

the above line was used to give certain vars to the url like ?currentpage=2
Now since php updated from 4 to 5 it isnt working anymore. I googled a lot but couldnt find anything like my problem.

Does anyone has an idea why this update could have changed the working of the

```
$_SERVER['argv'][0];
```

Greets

Comment: From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php): "*Note: This variable is not available when `register_argc_argv` is disabled.*".

Comment: But why would your code access `argv` instead of just `$_GET[]` in the first place?

Comment: thanx! helped a lot. and there are a lot of diffrent vars that get passed by the url. so tought this was more easy?